# Create branch from head and commit from previous commit

Tags: git

For my work, i need to manage my project with GIT. It's new for me, and i don't know all the tricks.

I have to handle the following case (from oldest to newest):

```
A
|
B
|
C (head)
```

However, i need to correct a bug on version B without lost version C (which is currently non official). I've thought to do this:

```
A
|
B
| \
D  C

D:(head)
```

But if i could create branch C, i can't "go back" to B and commit files to create D.
Maybe it is not the correct way to use GIT, however how i can do this ?

Thank you

Comment: Thanks to all for your answer and your explanations.
It was very interessing and usefull.

Answer (score 4):

> i can't "go back" to B and commit files to create D

Yes you can :

```
# create a brackup branch to store commit C for later
git branch <name-for-your-store-branch>

# then return to B
git reset --hard B

# make your needed changes here

# then add and commit as usual, for example
git add .
git commit -m "Done this and that"
```

You'll end up with (here I assumed "master" for your main branch)

```
A---B---D <<< master <<< HEAD
     \
      C <<< your "store" branch
```

Answer (score 2):

To expand a bit on [RomainValeri's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59945183/1256452), remember these things about Git:

- Git stores *commits*.  Any given commit's "true name" is its hash ID, that big ugly string of letters and digits that `git log` prints after the word "commit".  (You can abbreviate these if you like, up to a point.)  These *look* random, but actually aren't random at all.
- Each commit contains a full and complete snapshot of *every* file.<sup>1</sup>  It also contains a backwards-pointing link to its *parent* commit, which is what we're drawing when we do these `A--B--C` kind of diagrams.  I like to draw them left-to-right for StackOverflow, and vertically with newer commits towards the top—the way `git log --graph` draws them—in some other situations.  You can and should practice drawing these things.

The files that are inside each commit are stored in a special, read-only, Git-only, compressed—sometimes highly compressed—format.  Git itself is pretty much the only program that can work with these.  Plus, they're read-only: nothing, not you, not even Git itself, can *change* them.  Once you make a commit, that commit is frozen for all time.  If that commit is bad—if you need to replace it—you end up having to make a new and improved commit instead, shoving the old bad commit off to the side.  That is, you might start with:

```
A--B--C
```

and then decide that `C` is bad, and use `git commit --amend` to fix it up.  This doesn't actually *change* `C` at all, because it can't.  Instead, it shoves `C` aside and makes a new-and-improved commit: `C'`.  The parent of `C'` is the same as the parent of `C`:

```
     C
    /
A--B--C'
```

The old commit is still there, it's just moved out of the way to make room for `C'`.

Once you have this stuff down—that commits store files, in a read-only fashion, and link back to earlier commits—you will realize two things:

1. How can we possibly get any work done?  The files inside commits are read-only, frozen for all time, and completely unreadable to anything *but* Git.  We need *ordinary* files that we can *change*.
2. How do we *find* the *right* commits?

The answer to question #1 is that Git provides us a place in which to do our work, which Git calls the *working tree* or *work-tree*.  (Old versions of Git used to call this *working directory* or similar names, but it's too easy to confuse this with the working directory string that the `pwd` command prints, so now it's the work-tree or working tree.)  Git will copy files *out* of commits, into this work area.<sup>2</sup>

The answer to question #2 is where *branch names* come in.  Each branch name stores the hash ID of just *one* commit.  When we draw commits this way:

```
A--B--C   <-- branch
```

or:

```
C  <-- branch
|
B
|
A
```

we are drawing what Git really has internally: a name, like `branch`, *pointing to* (containing the hash ID of) a commit like `C`.  Meanwhile commit `C` itself has the hash ID of—or *points to*—its parent commit `B`, and so on.

You can, at any time, create a *new* branch name, by picking any existing commit and saying: *Make this new branch name point to this existing commit.*  You do this with the `git branch` command.  So to make some new name, like `hotfix`, point to some existing commit, you can run:

```
git branch hotfix <hash>
```

where `<hash>` is the hash ID, obtained perhaps by cut-and-paste of the hash ID that `git log` printed.  Now you have:

```
A--B   <-- hotfix
    \
     C   <-- branch
```

When you run `git checkout name`, Git uses the *name* to find the commit.  That's the *commit* that comes out into your work-tree (and index; see footnote 2), so that you can work on it.  When you run `git commit`, Git makes a *new commit (from whatever is in your index at that time), which chooses the random-looking hash ID.<sup>3</sup>

This is also how you make new branches in general.  It's just that you start with:

```
A--B--C   <-- master
```

and then make a new name, like `develop`, that points to commit `C` itself:

```
A--B--C   <-- develop, master
```

We now need to know *which branch name we're using*, so in these kinds of drawings, we can add the special name `HEAD` in all uppercase, and attach it to a branch name, like this:

```
A--B--C   <-- develop (HEAD), master
```

If we now make a new commit, what Git does is write the new commit's hash ID into the *name to which `HEAD` is attached*, giving us:

```
A--B--C   <-- master
       \
        D   <-- develop (HEAD)
```

If we make the name `hotfix` point to commit `B`, and then do a `git checkout hotfix`, we get:

```
A--B   <-- hotfix (HEAD)
    \
     C   <-- master
      \
       D   <-- develop
```

Commit `B` is in our work area, so that we can change files (and in our index so that we can commit).  We do our work, `git add` files (to copy them back into the index—see footnote 2), and `git commit`, and Git makes a *new* commit, which gets a new unique big ugly hash ID but we'll just call it `E`, and then Git writes `E`'s hash ID into the name `hotfix` because that's where `HEAD` is attached:

```
A--B--E   <-- hotfix (HEAD)
    \
     C   <-- master
      \
       D   <-- develop
```

**Note that whatever we do, we're always *adding new commits* to the repository.**  The existing commits don't change.  They *can't!*  We just add *new* ones.

The *branch names* move around!  They always point to the *last* commit (on the branch).  That is, in fact, one definition of "a branch", in Git: it's the *last* commit.  Or, sometimes when we say "a branch" we mean *the name itself*, or sometimes we mean *some set of commits leading up to and including that last commit*.  The word *branch*, in Git, is kind of ambiguous.  It helps to think in terms of *commits* first.  Add the branch names later.  Use the names to *find* the commits; that's what Git does.

---

<sup>1</sup>Technically, each contains only a snapshot of the files that it contains.  Consider, for instance, what happens if you make commit `C` after putting a totally new file into it, that didn't exist when you made commit `B`.  Existing commit `B` *can't* change, and it doesn't have that file.  So `C`, and later commits, will have the file; `B` won't have the file.  Each commit will have a full and complete snapshot of all the files that it has.

Another way to think of this is: a commit is a frozen-for-all-time *copy* of some set of files.  What copies of files go into a *new* commit?  The answer is stored in Git's index; see footnote 2.

<sup>2</sup>You would think, then, that Git would make new commits from the work area, but it doesn't.  Instead, Git makes new commits from whatever is in Git's *index*.  The index, which Git also calls the *staging area*, or (rarely these days) the *cache*, is a pretty big topic and we won't cover it properly here.  It's important to understand it in order to use Git effectively, but see other postings or articles about it.  You can, however, think of it as containing a *third* copy of each file.  When you run `git add`, Git copies the work-tree copy of the file you're `git add`-ing into the index copy.  When you run `git checkout`, Git copies the frozen copy of *each* file, from the existing commit you are checking out, into the index copy, and also into the work-tree.  This is not 100% correct, but suffices to get started.

<sup>3</sup>This hash ID depends on:

- the entire snapshot;
- the *parent* commit hash ID;
- your name and email address and so on, as recorded in the commit;
- your log message, as recorded in the commit; and
- even the date-and-time at which you *make* the commit.

If you know in advance all of these things, you can predict what the hash ID of your commit will be.  But nobody knows when they're going to make a new commit, until they actually make it.  It's not worth pre-calculating a hash, then waiting until the exact right second and running `git commit`.  Just make the commit and find out what hash it got.  And if you make it again, even with everything else the same, it'll get a different hash this time, because it's no longer the same *time*.

(This does, however, lead to a particular kind of weirdness if you use a *program* to make identical commits very rapidly on two different branch names.  Since they're made at the same time, from the same stuff, using the same parent, they get the same hash ID.  It's not *broken* or a *bug*, but these identical commits get identical hash IDs, so that the two branch names point to the *same* commit!  But that's what we start with in the first place, when we do this.)

Answer (score 0):

So you have `A-B-C` on branch let's say `dev` (with everything nicely commited). You would like to have `A-B-D` on branch `dev` but you would like to have `A-B-C` on branch `non_official`.

**branch non_official**

```
# we are on dev (A-B-C with head on C)
git checkout -b non_official
```

**branch dev**

```
# we are on dev (A-B-C with head on C, same as non_official) 
git reset --hard <hash-commit-B>
```

or in this case, since `B` is the commit just before `head`:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

And now we have `A-B` on `dev` and you can add some other commit (`D`).